# Apparent FPS random drop in webcam when using OpenCV in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, frame-rate

I'm coding a simple OpenCV example to get webcam frames during 5 seconds (~150 frames if the cam works at ~30fps).

After making some tests, I see that sometimes I get ~140 out of 150 frames (acceptable, I guess), but sometimes ~70. Even worse, sometimes the camera seems to suffer from those frame drops and keep in that state for hours.

To investigate the problem further, I stripped my program until I still have that issue even if I only read frames, but do not write them to disk. I've set a cron job in order to run a 5-seconds capture every minute, and I've been seen things like this:
[image]

I think the two first small drops were due to system being busy, but the big, permanent one occurred in the middle of the night. In the morning, I stopped the cron job, touched some things in the code (I can't remember exactly what) and started the test again, to see a gradual recovery followed by a new drop after 2-3 hours:
[image]

Since yesterday, I've turned off the computer for several hours, booted it up again and covered the webcam to ensure constant light conditions, but the frame count is still low, and stuck on 70. Also, it's really weird that the drop (70 frames out of 150) goes to exactly half the max frames I've seen in this camera (140 frames out of 150).

The webcam model is Logitech C525. I'm also testing in a Macbook Pro Late 2016 Facetime HD camera and there I see a constant 117 frames out of 150. A colleague of mine also sees frame drops in his laptop. Is there some problem with my code? Could it be thread priority?

```
// Call the program like this: ./cameraTest pixelWidth pixelHeight fps timeLimit
// timeLimit can be 1 to run a fixed 5-seconds capture, or 0 to wait for 150 frames.

#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "iostream"
#include "thread"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

using namespace cv;
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;


VideoCapture camera(0);
bool stop = false;
int readFrames = 0;


std::string getTimeStamp()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  char buffer[80];

  time(&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

  strftime(buffer,sizeof(buffer),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",timeinfo);
  std::string timeStamp(buffer);
  return timeStamp;
}


void getFrame()
{
    Mat frame;
    camera >> frame;
    // camera.read(frame);
    // cv::imwrite("/tmp/frames/frame" + std::to_string(readFrames) + ".jpg", frame);
    readFrames++;
}


void getFrames()
{
    Mat frame;

    while(!stop)
    {
        camera >> frame;
        // cv::imwrite("/tmp/frames/frame" + std::to_string(fc) + ".jpg", frame);
        readFrames++;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc < 5)
    {
        std::cout << "Usage: width height fps timeLimit" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if(!camera.isOpened())
    {
        std::cout << "Couldn't open camera " << getTimeStamp() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (!fs::is_directory("/tmp/frames"))
    {
        if(system("mkdir -p /tmp/frames") != 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Error creating /tmp/frames/" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    if (!fs::is_empty("/tmp/frames"))
    {
        system("exec rm /tmp/frames/*");
    }

    camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, atoi(argv[1]));
    camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, atoi(argv[2]));
    camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, atoi(argv[3]));
    //camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC, CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'));

    bool timeLimit(atoi(argv[4]));

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    int waitSeconds = 5;

    if(timeLimit)
    {
        std::thread tr(getFrames);
        usleep(waitSeconds * 1e6);
        stop = true;
        tr.join();
    }
    else
    {
        while(readFrames < 150)
        {
            getFrame();
        }
    }

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << getTimeStamp() << " " << readFrames << "/" << atoi(argv[3]) * waitSeconds << " "
            << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count() << "ms"
            << " " << atoi(argv[1]) << "," << atoi(argv[2]) << "," << atoi(argv[3])
            << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it has to do with low-light conditions. As soon as I uncovered the camara, I saw the frames  increase to their expected value. So maybe on poor light conditions, the camera changes some settings or further processes the images, lowering its framerate.

[image]

Comment: Autoexposure -- for the usual webcam usage, it's more useful to actually see something albeit at low framerate, as opposed to getting an almost black image at full rate.